# PHPStorm not showing relationships of Symfony2 Doctrine Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, data-modeling, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 5 and Symfony2 Doctrine2 Entities.
I'm using annotations to specify relationships.

When I try to generate a diagram of all my bundles and entities it just shows a diagram of all the individual classes / entities but no relationships between the entities.

I thought this was supported by PHPStorm?

Comment: 1) Only classes/interfaces/traits are supported 2) It has no special support for Doctrine Entities yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know, the diagram generated by phpstorm only shows that classes extend another class or implement interfaces.

It looks like this:

[image]

New in PhpStorm 5 is the symfony2 support, eg. you can run the symfony2 `app/console` tool out of the IDE, and it supports MVC project view, but this hast nothing to do with the diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/). It has full support for Doctrine2 ORM, it can generate the complete diagram of your project (objects, relations and all). You can also edit the schemas in the visual environment and have the schema files generated automatically.

Comment: ORM Designer is now Skipper (ORM Designer3). It's available on the new site [www.skipper18.com](http://www.skipper18.com)